# Is there any free alternative to Mendeley desktop app on Windows?

Tags: software, reference-managers, reading, literature, document-organization

I have been using Mendeley for a very long time now. I use it for organizing and reading articles. I just noticed that it keeps removing files randomly from the folders and groups. I don't know the exact reason for this. I wonder if there is an alternative to the Mendeley desktop client for Windows.

Comment: While still using your mendeley account and database? Or are you asking for free reference managers in general? There are plenty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zotero is a free (and open source!) alternative: https://www.zotero.org/

There is a plenty of other tools (just google 'citation managers'), but I believe that Zotero's open source nature renders it preferable to all alternatives - including Mendeley, which belongs to the large commercial publisher Elsevier.

Comment: Please note that Mendeley online storage [allows up to 2GB](https://www.mendeley.com/settings/upgrade/) for free users, while Zotero [only allows 300MB](https://www.zotero.org/storage) for free users. Unlimited storage will cost you 10 $/month for Zotero and 13,75 $/month for Mendeley (if you choose the annual subscription)

Comment: You can also use your own pre-existing cloud storage solution to store your Zotero PDFs (although you have to be a little bit careful setting it up: https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/55909/sync-with-onedrive-dropbox-and-other-cloud-storage-services )

Comment: @BenBolker wow. this is amazing. thank you for sharing

Comment: Can we use Zotero without using any link to cloud storage?

Comment: @alper Yes. I use the desktop version without the cloud at work